# Optimization Model for Market Clearing using Uniform Pricing

Tags: optimization, markets, dynamic-optimization

**Dear all, can someone please share a simple example for market clearing via Uniform Pricing using an Optimization Model?**

I am trying to simulate a market using bid values with quantity and price, from supply and demand side. I am using pyomo as an optimization tool. However, all the models that I have come across for market clearing are either providing schedule or for pricing but have never come across a model that does both. Can someone share an example of this?